# insert if not exist , using auto incremental primary keys. mvc3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, insert, primary-key, auto-increment

i have a problem with auto incremental primary keys..

when im adding a student to my database, i can add the same student over and over again because the primary key of student is auto incremental so it is, of course, never repeated, i need to verify that the  SSN of the student does not already exist in the database before inserting.

how can i do that on mvc3?? (im totally new in .net and mvc3)

my code for create in the student controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Alumno alumno)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new administracionEntities())
            {
                db.Alumno.Add(alumno);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you insert check if input alumno.ssn doesnot exist like

```
db.Alumno.where(a=> a.ssn == alumno.ssn).Any()
```

if this returns true, then there exists a ssn in database.

There are different ways in which you can achieve this in MVC.In one of which, You can have this call in a separate call to controller than in Create Action. May be you can check if duplicate SSN exists through JQuery.Ajax call on SSN textbox blur event on client side.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "Get",
   url: "StudentController/DoesSSNExist",
   data: "ssn=#", 
   success: function(msg){
       if(msg)
        alert('ssn already exists');
   }
```

This is controller action

```
public bool DoesSSNExist(string ssn)
{
    return db.Alumno.where(a=> a.ssn == ssn).Any()
}
```

Comment: thank u pravin pawar!!! that worked!!! how can i send an error message? i know it sounds like adumb question, but i dont know the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In my model Class

```
public class Student {
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    [Remote("UsernameChecker", "Student")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller

```
public virtual JsonResult UsernameChecker(string Username){
    bool checkuser = db.Student.Any(i => i.Username == Username);
    return checkuser
        ? Json("Username already exists", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        : Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```